# Raspberry Pi wont boot until ethernet cable is connected

Tags: boot, emulation, boot-issues, retropie

I'm using the **RetroPie** distro, on a **Model-B** Pi.

The problem I'm having is that **everytime I turn on my Pi, it doesn't boot until I plug an ethernet cable connected to a powered PC**.

It just stays on the "pre-boot" screen, after some [INFO] messages, with the Raspberry Pi logo on it. (With the underscore cursor flashing)

After I plug the cable, it resumes it's boot normally, without any further dependency from the ethernet cable/connection.

The expected behavior is that the Raspberry Pi should boot automatically into EmulationStation.

Does anyone know how the ethernet connection requirement could be ignored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is a DHCP client which is waiting for a response on the boot process.

Comment the eth0 section inside the /etc/network/interfaces file. Or change to a static address.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how to achieve this?
(Currently I'm connecting to my Pi using a static IP adress, for SSH and FTP access)

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is that you have some ip configuration getting set in the `cmdline.txt` file. If you do, then remove that data.

It does not seem to be related to DHCP, because if you change the timeout in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf it still waits that long.